# Create 15-min slots between two hours in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I am working on simple task management tool.
I need to generate dropdown which shows available time slots between two particular hours in 15 min intervals, like

(input)
13:00 - 14:00
(output) 13:15, 13:30, 13:45, 15:00

(input)
10:00 - 13:00
(output) 10:00, 10:15, 10:30 ...... 13:00

What may be the simplest solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a simple generator:

```
import datetime

def time_slots(start_time, end_time):
    t = start_time
    while t <= end_time:
        yield t.strftime('%H:%M')
        t = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), t) +
             datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)).time()
```

And the use it like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start_time = datetime.time(13, 00)
>>> end_time = datetime.time(14, 00)
>>> list(time_slots(start_time, end_time))
['13:00', '13:15', '13:30', '13:45', '14:00']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
>>> beginning = datetime.strptime("10:00", "%H:%M")
>>> hours = 1
>>> times = [beginning + timedelta(minutes=x) for x in range(15, (60 * hours) + 15, 15)]

>>> times
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 15), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 30), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 45), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 11, 0)]
```