# How to create a slot interval between two hours in Django

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I am trying to create slot intervals from two given times ie

Input :

Start time : 1:00

End time : 2:00

Output:
1:00-1:15 , 1:15 - 1:30, 1:30-1:45 , 1:45 - 2:00

Code I am currently using:

THE SLOT GENERATOR

```
import datetime

def time_slots(start_time, end_time):
    t = start_time
    while t <= end_time:
        yield t.strftime('%H:%M')
        t = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), t) +
             datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)).time()
```

USAGE:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start_time = datetime.time(13, 00)
>>> end_time = datetime.time(14, 00)
>>> list(time_slots(start_time, end_time))
```

THE ISSUE IS :
If I give inputs as

Start time as 9:00am ie datetime.time(9, 00)

Endtime as 12:00am ie datetime.time(0, 00)

then i get an empty list , So how do i solve it

CODE REFERENCED FROM:
[Create 15-min slots between two hours in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279789/create-15-min-slots-between-two-hours-in-django)

Comment: Yes because the if condition fails as end_time > start_time, you can solve this by adding the day in the context as 12am will be next day

Comment: Endtime as 12:00am NOT ie datetime.time(0, 00), it should be `datetime.time(12, 0)`